# Media queries and Opera mini - where the mistake (min-width ...)

Tags: html, mobile, css, media-queries

Can someone explain to me, why this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vhCLs/ (or http://cssdesk.com/fPS2s )

does not work in Opera mini? 
On the example of these sites http://mediaqueri.es who work in the latest Opera Mobile is very good…
Maybe these sites use an extra javascript? (I tried to find it in the source code, but my searches are unsuccessful)

do not swear for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `max-device-with` instead of `max-width` for mobile support.